# Janrain engage: token_url not called from Firefox

Tags: firefox, callback, janrain

I have an application using Janrain Engage for login.
Everything works since few months, except on ONE machine from Firefox...

I have no clue for what reason, when I try to log-in from this machine (on my site or even on Janrain's admin site), I get the sign-in page, the I choose a provider, enter my information, validate and then, nothing happens !

Normal process trace is:

- GET
  https://XXXXXXX.rpxnow.com/signin/get_login_info?widget_type=auth&provider=google&time=1358864872301 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1144ms]
- POST http://XXXXXXX.rpxnow.com/redirect?loc=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2533ms]
- POST https:// my_token_url_on_mydomain [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 3667ms]

On the faulty machine, I just have the first GET, and then nothing else...
The token_url callback is never called, so I even do not have any trace on my server.

The machine where the problem occurs is my personnal machine at home. Same login attemps works like a charm with Chrome or IE. I did'nt find any specific settings in my Firefox configuration.

I'm afraid some potential customers can get the same behaviour as me and go away... Is anyone experimenting similar problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Froggy. You might have 3rd party cookies disabled in Firefox. That's the only thing I can think of that would cause that issue on a single browser. Go here for info on changing that setting: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-third-party-cookies/

Comment: Thanks Juan, you are right, **3rd party** cookies were disabled in Firefox options.

The first thing I tested when looking at this problem was to check if **cookies** were enabled, I think I was too confident to see this one...

Comment: I couldn't figure out why the social login worked in Edge and Internet Explorer but not Chrome and Firefox. But this was indeed the reason!